# SPI Configuration in TFT

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, serial, lvds, deserialiser

I have a TFT which requires SPI Communication interface to get it configured.

My questions :

1. When we say, "configure the tft", what do we actually do? Do we set some bits or erase some bits inside he tft? If so, what purpose do they serve?
2. The TFT also has LVDS Data and LVDS Clock lines. Then why does it require a separate SPI interface to configure instead of using the LVDS Data to send the data and do the configuration?
3. I have a microcontroller and a deserializer. Can I use the Microcontroller with SPI interface for the configuration part and use Deserializer for sending LVDS Display data?

Comment: The data sheet should be quite explicit about this.

Comment: The LVDS lines are most probably just for transmission of pixel data. LVDS ([low voltage differential signalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling)) is used for high-speed transmissions to enable large displays _and_ high image rates. In contrary the speed requirements for control are much lower, SPI suffices. -- Which microcontroller, and which deserializer?

Comment: NXPS32K146 and MAX9278